# How to make a group of same values

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, typescript

I have a simply array and want to loop through the array which have some same key and value, and i want to make a group of those values which are the same and put the related item under that.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  data = [
    {
      'con': 'Usa',
      'city': 'ny',
      'town':'as'
    },
    {
      'con': 'Ger',
      'city': 'ber',
      'town':'zd'
    },
    {
      'con': 'Usa',
      'city': 'la',
      'town':'ss'
    }
  ];
  array: any[] = [];
  ngOnInit() {
    this.array = this.data;
  }
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array ">
  <h3>{{item.con}}</h3>
  <p>{{item.city}}</p>
  <p>{{item.town}}</p>
  <hr>
</div>
```

and i have a following result:

```
Usa
ny
as
-----
Ger
ber
zd
-----
Usa
la
ss
-----
```

but what i really wants is to make a group of those country with the same name and display the related cities and town under that with the following format:

```
[{
        "con": "usa",
        "area": [{
            "city": "ny",
            "town": "as"
        }, {
            "city": "la",
            "town": "ss"
        }]
    },
    {
        "con": "ger",
        "area": [{
            "city": "ber",
            "town": "zd"
        }]
    }
]
```

Comment: Which version of angular?

Comment: create an array of array in ngOnInit function

Comment: It is not right to change a question like that after answers have been given. What about my question above?

Answer (score 3):

Transform the data to an array with the consolidated objects, where the `cities` properties have arrays, like so

```
[
    { con: "Usa": cities: ["ny", "la"] },
    { con: "Ger", cities: ["ber"] }
]
```

You can build that data structure as follows:

```
this.array = Array.from(
    this.data.reduce(
        (map, {con, city}) => map.set(con, (map.get(con) || []).concat(city)), 
        new Map
    ), ([con, cities]) => ({ con, cities })
);
```

Then the HTML part becomes:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array ">
    <h3>{{item.con}}</h3>
    <div *ngFor="let city of item.cities ">
        <p>{{city}}</p>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your nice solution i have revised the question now i have other value and i want to put it under each city name. but i have problem with the structure. can you please see that. thanks

Comment: You should not change the question like that after answers have been given. It would be better if you would revert it to the original and ask a new question if necessary. The updated question does not mention any output format, only an object structure, so now it is not clear any more what you want. If your question is about pure object transformation and not any more about rendering, then you should also remove any information about rendering otherwise it is confusing. As said, that would better be done as a new question.

Comment: Any reaction ...?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort your JSON before passing to angular ngFor as bellow,

```js
 data = [
    {
      'con': 'Usa',
      'city': 'ny'
    },
    {
      'con': 'Ger',
      'city': 'ber'
    },
    {
      'con': 'Usa',
      'city': 'la'
    }
  ];


var expectedResult = data.sort(function (a, b) {
   return a.con.localeCompare(b.con);
});

console.log(expectedResult)
//OR
// change order as        return b.con.localeCompare(a.con);
```

Comment: Order can be changes as ->    return b.con.localeCompare(a.con);

Comment: How does this answer the question? The OP is not looking for ordering, but for grouping.

Comment: @trincot : here grouping will be automatically done using sorting with any order.

Comment: Are you sure? Note that in the desired output only two countries are output (each once). I don't see that happening with just ordering.

Comment: BTW, you mention JSON, but there is no JSON here.